# Why do I get error ORA-08002 when trying to get the currval of a sequence?

Tags: oracle, jdbc

In TOAD I can execute this query:

```
select my_seq.currval from dual;
```

But when I try to execute it in my application I get this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-08002: sequence MY_SEQ.CURRVAL is not yet defined in this session
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer is very simple: you have to read nextval at least once before you can use currval.

Comment: Execute a `select my_seq.nextval from dual` first and it should be good to go.

Comment: While this is corrent, you have to keep in mind that calling `.nextval` will also iterate the sequence (increase the sequence by [usually] 1). So if you just want to know the current sequence-number, this creates holes in the id-sequence...

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for this is to execute this sql:

```sql
select LAST_NUMBER-1 currval from all_sequences t where t.sequence_name = 'put here your sequence_name';
```

Comment: This workaround will not work in the many cases, such as RAC, cached sequences, multi-user environments, etc.